# How to get all annotation's attribute for an annotation type used for function and its class?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations

```
@CustomAnnotation(chat = false) 
public class Controller {
    @CustomAnnotation(login = true)
    protected String getResult() {
        // function body 
    }

    protected String getMark() {
       // function body 
    }
}
```

Code for CustomAnnotation:

```
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
    boolean login() default false;
    boolean chat() default true;
}
```

Here, the CustomAnnotation can be applied to both class and its methods. How to find the declared annotation for the function getResult(). 
Assuming method is "getResult", method.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class) will return [@com.xyz.CustomAnnotation(chat=true, login=true)] but I want [@com.xyz.CustomAnnotation(chat=false, login=true)] as class is also annotated with CustomAnnotation.

I want all the annotation attribute at once.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two completly different annotations. You have to see annotations as markers and you have marked the method with login=true and the class with chat=false

Comment: Class is marked with "chat=false" as it applies to all the methods in it and "getResult()" is marked as "login=true" as it only applies to "getResult" method not the other methods. For other methods, it is "login=false" by default.